# How to persist Mongoose virtuals through Passport

Tags: node.js, mongoose, passport.js, passport-local

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41123708/how-to-access-mongoose-virtuals-in-express) post, which explains how to keep the virtual fields when calling `toObject` and `toJSON` methods. However, my problem is that I'm trying to use the `req.user` object set by the Passport.js local strategy, which is (apparently) not a Mongoose model.

I have a `User` schema that stores the first and the last name, and I am using a virtual property `name.full` to call the full name with a space in-between. I don't have to use a virtual for this, no, but I really want to.

```
const schema = new Schema({
  name: {
    first: "john",
    last: "smith"
  }
})
  .virtual("name.full")
  .get(function () {
    return this.name.first + " " + this.name.last;
  });

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", schema);
```

Now, I have a router that points to `/login`, where the user can post his/her login information and Passport.js will authenticate using a local strategy.

After the user is authenticated, I save the user's information inside the Express.js session using the `req.user` object automatically set by Passport.js.

```
function redirectToHome (req, res) {
    req.session.contextVars = { user: req.user };
    res.redirect("/home");
}
```

So the entire post router looks like:

```
router.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", { failureRedirect: "login" }), redirectToHome);
```

The problem here is that, even though the `req.user` is an Object that can do everything a Mongoose model can do -- even calling the instance methods -- but it doesn't have any of the virtual fields. I set `toObject: { virtuals: true }` and `toJSON: { virtuals: true }` like suggested in the aformentioned post because I thought maybe Passport.js calls one of the two under the hood before storing data in the session object, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

I am using `express-session` *and* `passport.session()` for session management.

**app.js**

```
const express = require("express")
    , app = express();
const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("passport");

app.use(session({
    secret: "secret key",
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}));

app.use(passport.initialize())
    .use(passport.session());
```

I am trying to read this data in a `pug` file, which is receiving the data as an `Object` through `res.render`.

**routes/index.js**

```
router.get("/home", function (req, res) {
    res.render("home", { LOCAL_DATA: req.session.contextVars });
});
```

**home.pug**

```
... usual head stuff
body
  p #{JSON.stringify(LOCAL_DATA.user)}
```

I can think of a few work-arounds, but I'd like to resolve the issue this specific way. Does anyone know how to make sure Passport.js assigns the `req.user` object with all virtual fields visible?

Thank you.

Comment: there is no persistence as the code shows it in the mongoose model. If I have understood your query correctly, you are missing the call to the save method on the schema object. Please refer to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly, since there is no save call on the mongoose model, (the mongoose model that you are using simply returns a schema that has no data on the virtual object. As the test shows, when the call to the static create method is made (commented in the test code of the screenshot), the test passes as the data is persisted in the virtual object with a call to the save on the 'user' object.

So, after creating the data and persisting it with the save method, return the new object and not the schema as below:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),Schema=mongoose.Schema;
var schema = new Schema({
  name: {
    first: "john",
    last: "smith"
  }
})
  .virtual("name.full")
  .get(function () {
    return this.name.first + " " + this.name.last;
  });
var NewUser = new mongoose.Schema(schema);
// Below code added by Jv
NewUser.statics.create = function (params, callback) {
  var newUpdate = new NewUser(params);
  newUpdate.save(function(err, result) {
    callback(err, result);
  });
  return newUpdate;
};
var User = mongoose.model('Model', NewUser);
module.exports = User;
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, no, I'm working with a `user` instance, so this is after the call to `create()` have been made. The virtual property _does_ exist, as I can test it on the server-side code. The problem is that when Passport.js tries to save the user object in `req.user` after its local strategy, the virtual property becomes unavailable.

Comment: Where are you using the below line?

router.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", { failureRedirect: "login" }), redirectToHome);

Can you share the code to understand the flow?

Comment: Can you share the code to understand the flow?

Because that would set right the usage of "req.user" or should it be "req.body.user" or "req.params.user"

Comment: I'm afraid my code is written across 3 different files and it might make (already lengthy) question too long. `req.user` variable is automatically set by Passport.js, and the local strategy used essentially _requires_ me to have a saved user instance to be authenticated. I for a fact know that it's an issue with the way Passport.js is saving the user object.

Comment: Everything except the virtual property worked. To answer your question, though, that line is used in `routes/index.js`, which is required in `app.js`. I went with a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Mongoose documentation:

> If you use toJSON() or toObject() mongoose will not include virtuals
>   by default. This includes the output of calling JSON.stringify() on a
>   Mongoose document, because JSON.stringify() calls toJSON(). Pass {
>   virtuals: true } to either toObject() or toJSON().

When passport puts the user on the request, it is probably getting called with `toJSON()` or `toObject()` by default before the payload is sent back to the requestor.

If I'm not mistaken, I think that you'll have to explicitly call `toJSON` or `toObject()` and pass in `{ virtuals: true }` in your Passport callback when you put it on the request object.